# How to install TeamViewer on OpenWRT or LEDE?

Tags: router, wireless-router, openwrt, teamviewer, lede

There is no automatic IPK package for OPKG installation so it can't be installed like other distributions like debian or ubuntu. My router has VGA port.

I only need Teamviewer functionality to login from WAN as it does with my Centos 7 server, easy login without any hassle from any TeamViewer client.

On my Centos 7, I'm able to get shell to login and run the router thru it, which is enough for me to program our nationwide routers. Can it be compiled from source? With TeamViewer I don't need to find the IPs from our routers, just a direct login, even by naming the routers to access is what we are looking for. Routers get dinamic Ips and its a problem to call the user and ask all the time their new IPs.

Comment: I put you you that TeamViewer is not a great solution. Why not set up some VPN infrastructure do you can securely log in to your clients routers without the overheads or run some kind of script to periodically / on interface up change the IP address? Both solutions would be easier then bring yo run teamviewer.

Comment: TeamViewer have some very nice features that we can use. I have installed TViewer on a couple of our clients Centos 7, and we can nicely, without any IP finding out, VPN or any problems can loging from any celular or tablet. We are investigating compiling TViewer for our routers, name the routers and our techs can help out remotely, very handy tool to loging, you can even view all the routers online and offline from your cell or PC. We will eventually compile it and install on all our routers. We are in the Jungle on South America, very bad connectivity here. Only satellite VSAT routers

Comment: You are aware that TeamViewer is a proprietary service, right? (ie it's going to be very difficult to get the source code for it) Also, if you have bad connectivity why would you use a bandwidth heavy screen casting program rather then much lighter weight web page and shell?

Comment: Yes Im aware, but there is a free version, if we deploy for commercial use, my clients will be happy to pay their fees. We will not use full desktop, we need only to login without GUI, You are right, we have tested the bandwith used on Centos server shell and is in the order of kb transfer rates, can be used without problems. If you used full GUI then is not suitable for low bw. I have found some instructions to install using tar, tommorrow I will test on one of our routers and let you know https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/How-to-use-the-TAR-package-for-Linux/ta-p/30664

Comment: Yes - you may be able to deploy a suitable binary, which is different to something you can compile.

Comment: Today I tested both versions 64 and 32 bit and follow instructions, but was not able to make it run on my setup. Will do some more testing and install some dependencies. @davidgo question? How can I setup VPN on routers that I dont handle their IPs? They are private IPs from satellite providers. I only have access to my routers onsite, but every time the IP changes... Got to call customer on site to get the IP. The only solution I have so far is ask customer to setup a laptop to get there and connect thru TeamViewer.

Comment: I would set up an OpenVPN server on a VM at a location close to the path data travels (to reduce latency), then set up a simple CA system and issue appropriate certs to each client and have your and each of the rotuters acting as VPN clients  to the server, allowing you to connect on a private IP across the VPN as mapped out and controlled by the VPN server config.